Как в Selenium не показывать окно терминала перед запуском браузера?
При запуске браузера появляется окно терминала которое мне не нужно, как его убрать подскажите. Что то ни как с options не могу разобраться как и куда его писать. Вот что имею сейчас.
 string chromeDriverDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverDir);
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/");


Тип "консольное приложение" в свойствах проекта поменяйте на другой.

@aepot там все гут, просто перед открытием самого браузера запускается его консоль, я когда то эту проблему решал, но это было год назад, а сейчас снова столкнулся и не помню как я это сделал.

Может кому пригодится.
        string chromeDriverDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, new ChromeOptions());
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/");

